# How to write a nested loop for elements of a list so that the combination of elements is not repeated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

My current code is:-

```
team=['Dragons','Wolves','Nightriders','Lords']
for home_team in team:
    for away_team in team:
        if home_team!=away_team:
            print(home_team,"vs",away_team)
```

For which the output is

> Dragons vs Wolves
>
> Dragons vs Nightriders
>
> Dragons vs Lords
>
> Wolves vs Dragons
>
> Wolves vs Nightriders
>
> Wolves vs Lords
>
> Nightriders vs Dragons
>
> Nightriders vs Wolves
>
> Nightriders vs Lords
>
> Lords vs Dragons
>
> Lords vs Wolves
>
> Lords vs Nightriders

Now I want to alter this code so that two teams don't face each other twice
for eg. if there is Wolves vs Lords there shouldn't be Lords vs Wolves

Comment: use `itertools.combinations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the nested for loop after the current index, because the previous words are already matched.

```
team=['Dragons','Wolves','Nightriders','Lords']

for i in range(len(team)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(team)):  
        print(team[i], ' vs ', team[j])
```